# Application.Designer.vb file is duplicated when change startup form for VBNET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a VBNet project in Visual Studio 2019, today I face this issue suddenly:

- When I change the startup form (which I did million times before without errors) to another form, the file `Application.Designer.vb` is duplicated with new name `Application1.Designer.vb`
- This file leads to build error: `'Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.`
- If I try to remove file `Application1.Designer.vb` then `File Not Found` error will be thrown.
- If I remove the compile tag for `Application1.Designer.vb` in the project vbproj file then build fails but no error is shown.

I could mess up with the app settings but I am now completely stuck and have no idea to run my project since these are all auto generated.

Please suggest anything that I should check. Thanks all!

[image]

Comment: "Application1.Designer.vb".  That doesn't look good, there must be only one.  Click the "Show All Files" toolbar button in the Solution Explorer window so you can see these files under the "My Project" node and fix the damage.

Comment: I already tried to remove that `Application1.Designer.vb` but the problem is that when I change startup form then this file is auto-generated again. I am not sure why

Comment: I think removing the file name `Application.Designer.vb` will solve the issue, I am able to switch startup form after that.